# backtrack 5 rc3 wireless not detected, even after compat drivers installed

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, drivers, backtrack

**Stock Drivers**

so after running `ifconfig`:

> lo no wireless extentions
>
> eth0 no wireless extentions

running `airmon-ng`

returns the headings only, no adapters are show
(I am typing this from memory, I am dual booting and I have no internet conenctivity bt5, so I am typing this in Windows)

**After Compat Drivers installed**

I downloaded version 3.6 of compat drivers, but no luck

Wicd - gives error ("could not connect to d-bus", which seems like it is normal) but it does not show any networks, before and after

> root@bt:~# lspci -vnn | grep -i net
>
> 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0887] (rev c4) 03:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek
>   Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
>   controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)

by the way, I have Intel Centrino N-2230 wireless adapter

anyone have any suggestions

UPDATE

```
root@bt:~# modinfo | grep iwlwifi
Usage: modinfo [-0][-F field][-k kernelversion][-b basedir]  module...
 Prints out the information about one or more module(s).
 If a fieldname is given, just print out that field (or nothing if not found).
 Otherwise, print all information out in a readable form
 If -0 is given, separate with nul, not newline.
 If -b is given, use an image of the module tree.

root@bt:~# modinfo iwlwifi | grep version
version:        in-tree:
srcversion:     AE4E3DF7D798BEFFB0EEA59

root@bt:~# modinfo iwlwifi | grep firmware
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (int)
```

Comment: Are you running this inside a VM? If not, can you post the output of lspci -vnn | grep -i net

Comment: @MariusMatutiae

    root@bt:~# lspci -vnn | grep -i net

    02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0887] (rev c4) 03:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)

by the way, I have Intel Centrino N-2230 wireless adapter

Comment: Are you running Kali inside a VM?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae No, I am dual booting W7 (64) & BT5 (64 Gnome)

Comment: your driver is iwlwifi. Fisrt check whether it is loaded, modinfo | grep iwlwifi. If it is loaded, we should see the version: modinfo iwlwifi | grep version. Lastly, ceck that you have the firmware, modinfo iwlwifi | grep firmware. Pls post this output here.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae check end of post